# unable to open mkb files in windows

Tags: marmalade

Am getting an error while opening .mkb files of marmalade in windows.

It shows the following error while trying to open the sample applications .mkb file :

```
C:\Marmalade\6.2\s3e\makefile_builder\mkb.py
C:\Marmalade\6.2\examples\IwGx\IwGxBasicLighting.mkb
Building project: c:/Marmalade/6.2/examples/IwGx/IwGxBasicLighting.mkb
Executing: 'c:\marmalade\6.2\s3e\bin\mdev.bat update'
Downloading: http://source.madewithmarmalade.com/packages/6.2/Packages
error: error downloading url: http://source.madewithmarmalade.com/packages/6.2/Packages (<urlopen error (10060, 'Operation timed out')>)
c:/marmalade/6.2/modules/iwutil/iwutil.mkf(19) : 
error: Executing 'c:\marmalade\6.2\s3e\bin\mdev.bat update' failed. (return code 1)
FAILED (error code=3)*
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have any active internet connection to open the mkb. Marmalade needs to download certain update files for license check and module updates to work correctly. Since you might be running marmalade for the first time, it throws the error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I have internet connection and even the [Packages link](http://source.madewithmarmalade.com/packages/6.2/Packages) is opening and showing the list of packages in browser

@govardhan

Comment: Marmalade couldn't access the url, it's clearly mentioned in the error. Either you've proxies enabled or there'd be some other restriction which might be blocking the access. Try choosing some other connection to update the packages for the first time. Later on it'll run fine without internet connection for some time.